# How to train a chunker on CONLL 2000 Corpora in Python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, chunking

I am new to Python, so I don't much about it. I am using nltk to tag Parts of speech in a sentence. I wan to chunk them afterwards. I am done with POS tagging. I don't know how to train chunker on CONLL 2000 corpora.

Comment: Easy as pie: Read [chapter 7](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html) of the nltk book. [Section 2](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html#Chunking) is about training a chunker on the CONLL 2000 corpus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [nltk-trainer](https://github.com/japerk/nltk-trainer) python package.

```
python train_chunker.py conll2000
```